# IDEA compiler error Unknown version '8', no version setting will be given to the compiler

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I try to run `jetty:run-exploded -f pom.xml` in IDEA,but it get error `Unknown version '8', no version setting will be given to the compiler` when compile.How can I fix it?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjl7s.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCIu.png)

[setting java compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SifNl.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack Overflow, please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it will help you to ask questions that poeple on this site can help you with.

Comment: Try opening `File->Project Structur` there you'll have the "Project language level" and set it to highest possible.

Comment: I would confirm all the modules in the `Project Structure` are using the right SDK, as your `project structure` screenshot shows a dependency on `docx-api` which itself could have a wrong SDK. You can also confirm that Maven is configured to use the right SDK and if you aren't running adhoc maven goals that the Run Profile is configured to the correct SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem in my `pom.xml`.
Change the `8` to `1.8` in `<source>` and `<target>` elements.

The correct xml show as follow:

```xml
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```